# How to realize cummulative sum without built-in function?

Tags: clickhouse

I need to realize cumulative summing per each day.

For example my data set is as follows:

```
buyer | bread | date      |
---------------------------
b1    |   2   | 2018-01-01|
b1    |   3   | 2018-01-02|
b1    |   1   | 2018-01-04|
b2    |   2   | 2018-01-02|
```

I need to get selection as follows:

```
buyer | cum_sum_on_01_01 | cum_sum_on_01_02 | cum_sum_on_01_03 | cum_sum_on_01_04 | cum_sum_on_01_05 |...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
b1    |        2         |        5         |         5        |      6           |       6          |...
b2    |        0         |        2         |         2        |      2           |       2          |...
```

How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See: [How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) The expectation on Stack Overflow is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point of `without built-in function`? The only way to achieve cumulative sums in ClickHouse for now is `arrayCumSum`. So the answer is to build the candidate array and pass it to `arrayCumSum`. Here are the steps:

## step 1: building the bread array for each buyer

```
SELECT
    buyer,
    groupArray(bread) AS breads
FROM
(
    SELECT
        buyer,
        sum(bread) AS bread,
        date
    FROM bbd
    ALL RIGHT JOIN
    (
        WITH
            toDate('2018-01-01') AS min_date,
            toDate('2018-01-31') AS max_date
        SELECT
            arrayJoin(buyers) AS buyer,
            arrayJoin(arrayMap(i -> (min_date + toIntervalDay(i)), range(toUInt64((max_date - min_date) + 1)))) AS date
        FROM
        (
            SELECT groupUniqArray(buyer) AS buyers
            FROM bbd
        )
    ) USING (buyer, date)
    GROUP BY
        buyer,
        date
    ORDER BY
        buyer ASC,
        date ASC
)
GROUP BY buyer

┌─buyer─┬─breads──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ b1    │ [2,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] │
│ b2    │ [0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] │
└───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

## step 2: apply arrayCumSum for each buyer

replace `groupArray(bread) AS breads`  to `arrayCumSum(groupArray(bread)) AS breads`

```
┌─buyer─┬─breads──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ b1    │ [2,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6] │
│ b2    │ [0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] │
└───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is excellent, and you should indeed use the built-in arrayCumSum function for computing cumulative sums.  However, if one of the motivations of the original question was to find out how to create accumulate/folding style functions **in general** when they are not natively supported by ClickHouse (e.g., CumMax, CumMin, etc.), here is an approach that will work with any aggregate function in ClickHouse.

The core piece of logic to achieve this is to use arrayReduceInRanges and generate all tuple ranges of the form `(1, 1), (1, 2), ... (1, n)` with arrayMap and arrayEnumerate.  Then, whichever function you choose as the higher-order aggregate function for arrayReduceInRanges, e.g. 'sum' or 'max', will be turned into a cumulative array-based form of the function.  Here is what that logic looks like:

```
WITH arr as (SELECT groupArray(some_col) AS arr_some_col FROM some_table)
SELECT
    arrayReduceInRanges(
        'sum'
        arrayMap(x -> (1, x), arrayEnumerate(arr_some_col))
        arr_some_col
    )
FROM arr
```

From here, you can arrayJoin the values back out from the array or keep them in array form for further calculations.

For your specific application with bread, here's something that would work using the above core logic (assuming your table is named bread_data):

```
WITH ordered AS (SELECT * FROM bread_data ORDER BY date, buyer),
agg AS (
    SELECT
        buyer,
        untuple(
            arrayJoin(
                arrayZip(
                    groupArray(date),
                    arrayReduceInRanges(
                        -- 'sum' or any ClickHouse aggregate function.
                        'sum',
                        arrayMap(x -> (1, x), arrayEnumerate(groupArray(bread))),
                        groupArray(bread)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    FROM ordered
    GROUP BY buyer
)
SELECT buyer, _ut_1 AS date, _ut_2 as cum_bread
FROM agg
ORDER BY date
```

Notice the first `WITH` clause which orders the table by date and buyer so that the subsequent groupArray calls will be guaranteed to construct their arrays in the same, consistent order (ClickHouse documentation notes that otherwise any call to groupArray can construct the elements in a random order).

It may seem complex, but when you break it down using the first core logic piece and the fact that a lot of the syntax here is around array grouping and ungrouping so that we can do our main work in array space, it should hopefully make some intuitive sense.

The output will look like this:

```
+-------+------------+-----------+
| buyer | date       | cum_bread |
+-------+------------+-----------+                                                                           
| b1    | 2018-01-01 |         2 |                                                                           
| b2    | 2018-01-02 |         2 |                                                                           
| b1    | 2018-01-02 |         5 |                                                                           
| b1    | 2018-01-04 |         6 |                                                                           
+-------+------------+-----------+
```